# How to capture the first pattern after certain string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to filter the first datetime or that line after 'Report Date' which is '25/01/2011 2:23 AM' in the sample below. Can anyone help??

```
<td colspan="2">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" lang="en-AU">
<tr>
<td class="a31" style="WIDTH:39.50mm;word-wrap:break-word;HEIGHT:4.00mm;">Report Date</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" lang="en-AU">
<tr>
<td class="a10" style="WIDTH:48.00mm;word-wrap:break-word;HEIGHT:4.00mm;">25/01/2011 2:23 AM</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td colspan="11">
</td>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? You'll get better answers if you have a specific question about code that's not working like you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead. Using a RegEx for this special case *might* work, but long term is not really maintainable.

For your example this would work:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.html"); // path to your HTML file
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='a10']");
string myDateString = node.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to use regex to parse XML or HTML. It's complicated and there are already a lot of parsers that take care of all the details for you. In C# you can use [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for XML and [HtmAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use regex (since you asked...):

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"class="a10".*>(\d+/\d+/\d+\s\d+:\d+\sAM)");
MatchCollection MatchList = exp.Matches(InputText);
Match FirstMatch = MatchList[0];
```

This gets all of the matches, storing them in MatchList. The first (and only, for this case) result is stored in FirstMatch. You may be able to skip the list creation if there's only ever going to be one field you need to capture.

However, like others have stated, you really shouldn't be explicitly using regex for this problem.